# Browser download speeds are extremely slow

Tags: networking, router, browser, speed

I've been having some strange problems with download speeds on this computer lately. I can download at 5 Mbit/s (which is the max speed that comes to my modem) when I'm downloading games from Steam or torrenting stuff. Speedtest also shows a speed of 5 Mbit/s and I'm able to watch Youtube without any problems.

But the problem is, everything else is extremely slow. Browser download speeds are bouncing between 0.5-1 Mbit/s (if I'm lucky that is). The problem persists when I try to open any webpage (especially the ones with embedded images).

My Specs Are:

**OS**: Windows 7 32-bit / Arch Linux 64-bit

**CPU:** Core 2 Duo E6550 (2.33 GHz) OC'd to 3.5 GHz

**MOTHERBOARD:** ASUS Z5K-SE

**RAM:** 2GB

Also, I'm **connected over ethernet** to a ZyXEL P-660W-Tx router/modem

Now, I've done some troubleshooting myself beforehand and I concluded that:

- It's not a problem with the OS. The issue persists on Arch Linux.
- It's not a problem with the PC. I tried downloading stuff over wifi with my smartphone (ASUS Zenfone 2) and that was slow as hell too.
- It's (probably) not a hardware problem with the router since Torrents and Steam work OK.

I'm out of ideas at this point and would really like some help. Thanks in advance to anyone that helps.

QUICK EDIT: I am already using Google DNS so that rules out a DNS related problem too. (Also I flushed the DNS cache yesterday)

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary troubleshooting suggestions:

1. That *ZyXEL P-660W-Tx* -- some of those *600 series* models have
   [weak security](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-859/product_id-13533/Zyxel-P-660hw.html), particularly if using the router's default
   settings.  Possibly it can be reflashed with [newer firmware](ftp://ftp.zyxel.com.tr/Zyxel_urunleri/MODEMLER/ADSL_MODEMLER/P-660W-T1v3_ipv6/Firmware/TTNET/370TSE6D0.bin), or
   rebooted and reconfigured more securely.
2. Using Arch, install [`gkrellm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GKrellM) and while web browsing look for
   unexpected traffic on the network and CPU action.   Also reboot, then with nothing much running, test web
   traffic on a minimal web browser, like [`elinks`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELinks) (text) or [`dillo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dillo)
   and see if those are also slow.

Comment: I did as you said and didn't really notice anything strange. Browsing with dillo was not much different than firefox but elinks was quick, i assume that is because its a text only browser.

Comment: I must also add that pacman/pacaur downloads are slow too

Comment: @godofpain, If `dillo` is the same speed, that lowers the odds that some evil extension or javascript is slowing your browser.  Therefore test the router -- if you have a laptop, test it with the router, then bring it to some other network source and note any unreasonable speed differences.

Comment: I'm currently away from my laptop and don't have access any other network source. Would testing the line with an old router help?

Comment: Also don't know if it will help or not, but I tested the transfer speed between the pc and my phone using iperf and I was able to achieve speeds of 20 Mbit/s. So no problems regarding the LAN connection.

Comment: @godofpain, Re *"old router"*: Might help, but using another source known to be good seems more conclusive.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that but first i must find the old router. I'm sure it's somewhere around but I have to look. I'll report back once I find it.

Comment: I tried using an old router and the results were, weird. The overall download speed increased to 1.5-2 Mbps but still nowhere near the 5 Mbps that Speedtest shows.

Comment: @godofpain, A difference in speed between routers suggests that it's time to reflash that *Zyxel*.  I'm not sure if this SoftPedia [*P-660HW-T1 v3_3.70(BJZ.10)C0.zip* firmware](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/Router-Switch-Access-Point/Zyxel/ZyXEL-P-660HW-T1-v3-Gateway-Firmware-370BJZ10C0.shtml) would work... it might.  If it works then reconfigure and use a strong password.

Comment: The exact model is P-660W-T1 v3 , not P-660HW. So I'm afraid if there is a possibility of bricking my router. The router isn't exactly mine so I'm trying to be cautious here.

Comment: @godofpain, A more complete [*Zyxel* assortment is here](https://www.zyxel.com/osearch/dl-search.aspx?mci_country=us&access=p&entqr=0&getfields=*&sort=date:D:S:d1&output=xml_no_dtd&ie=UTF-8&btnG=Submit&client=us-en-dl&q=product&filter=0&mci_lang=en&ud=1&site=us-en-dl&oe=UTF-8&partialfields=dl-product:P-660HW-T1%20v3&proxystylesheet=us-en-dl&ip=172.23.23.6&proxyreload=$zyxel_cgi_proxyreload&start=0), but none of the models have the lone **W**, it's all **HW**.   There a [Turkish firmware update video for your model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgCbwGuxJ2g).  Where'd this router come from?

Comment: Yup, It's provided by a Turkish ISP, I should've mentioned that. I'll watch that video and see if the update fixes the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately even after a firmware update, the issue persists.

Comment: @godofpain, That's interesting.  BTW, for other readers with the same hardware, please provide a URL for the firmware update in question.

Comment: Good idea, here is the download: ftp://ftp.zyxel.com.tr/Zyxel_urunleri/MODEMLER/ADSL_MODEMLER/P-660W-T1v3_ipv6/Firmware/TTNET/370TSE6D0.bin